# Calculate conditional pdf of uniformly cos and sin

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose $\theta$ is uniformly distributed within the interval of $(0, 2\pi)$ and $X = \cos θ, Y = \sin θ.$ Now I need to figure out $f_Y(y|x).$

I get $f_Y(y|x) = f_{X,Y}(x,y)/f_X(x),$ where $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = 1/\pi$ since $X$ and $Y$ compose a uniformly distributed unit circle. $f_X(x) = \int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}} f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,dx,$   which results
in $(2/\pi)\sqrt{1-x^2}.$ So for $f_Y(y|x).$ I got  $0.5/\sqrt{1-x^2}.$

However, the solution given by the book is $0.5\delta(y-\sqrt{1-x^2}) + 0.5\delta(y+\sqrt{1-x^2})$. I'd like to know where I got it wrong?

Comment: [MathJax formatting](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation)

Comment: I formatted most of your question, but gave up on the part in quotes, because suddenly $\delta$ appears without definition. Please check what I have done to make sure it matches your intent, and explain $\delta$. (I guess it may be $\theta$ because there is an alternate form of $\theta$ ($\vartheta$) that might be confused with $\delta.$)

Comment: @BruceET: $\delta$ is the Dirac delta function.

Comment: @BrianTung: Obvious now. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The critical observation is that given any value of $X$ (provided that $X \not= \pm 1$), $Y$ can only hold two values: either $\sqrt{1-X^2}$ or $-\sqrt{1-X^2}$.  This is because $X^2+Y^2 = 1$ necessarily, in turn because $\cos^2 \theta + \sin^2 \theta = 1$.

Each of these is equally likely, so the proper PDF is the sum of impulses (i.e., the Dirac delta function $\delta$) each of intensity $\frac{1}{2}$ at $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ and $-\sqrt{1-x^2}$.  When $X = \pm 1$, these impulses coincide and form a single impulse of intensity $1$ at $0$.